# Start video from a specific time between seconds

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using videoView to play a video, but I want to start video from a specific time between seconds.
If I use this code :

```
int framevalue = 1000;
videoView.seekTo(framevalue)
```

video will start playing at second 1.

But If I give the framevalue this value:

```
int framevalue = 1400;
videoView.seekTo(framevalue)
```

video will start playing at second 1 again, but I want that video start at 1.4 second.
is there any way to solve my problem please?

Comment: Have you tried :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: @Shiva Yes it works! Thank u for your suggestion